Is there a mathematical formula or a list of frequencies (Hz) of notes?
I want to create an app that generates the notes played on a standard bass guitar (4 strings, standard tuning). For this, I need the Hz value of the notes from low E (41 Hz, I think) on up.
Is this a simple math problem, where each half-tone is a certain value greater than the previous note? If not, then is there a chart somewhere that shows the Hz values of what I'm thinking of as "E1" (open E string) on up to "F4" (G string, fret 22)?
If that's confusing, here's a chart that shows how I've got them numbered:


There's others here who know the maths better than me so I'll leave a proper answer to them, but it's a bit of a can of worms to understand how the notes we use map to specific frequencies. To be 100% accurate you'll need to learn a bit about tuning systems vs pure intervals. However you could use a list of the frequencies found in so called 'equal temperament' mapped to your table and it would work just fine, but it wouldn't be completely accurate to a well tuned bass, and actual frequencies would differ depending on HOW you tuned the bass too (ie 5th fret > open vs 5th & 7th fret harmonics)

I googled for such a list, but didn't find one; I'll have to look harder, I guess, as one must be out there. If anyone finds one, I'll bountify their answer, though.

If you want the single frequency of each tone, that's very simple. Chamber A and twelfth root of 2 and you're done. But if you want to emulate the timbre of the guitar (or any other instrument), then it also includes overtones or the time envelope and that gets complicated.

You tried to google? What keywords? I put in tone frequency table and got a wide selection (though they're mostly titled "note frequency chart" or the like). (And not that you even really need it.)

You should decide on tuning system and reference pitch like A4 being 440. That should give you a bunch of formulas for many occasions. Pythagorean and just intonation are special cases of N-limit tuning systems, then you have a bunch of systems based on equal steps in logarithmic space called something like N-EDO or N-TET. I don't know difference of special cases like odd limit or prime limit. I usually tune my instruments with perfect fifths or perfect fourths, then they are a simple ratio like 440/660, unless the instrument is fretted then usually I try to get it good where I will play...

I have found tables that lists all midi notes and their equal temperament pitches. I have to google each time...

I can't think how this could be useful to any bass player. Please enlighten me. Also, don't fall into the trap that so many guitarists are in - flats don't exist.

@B.ClayShannon-B.CrowRaven this is the top hit on googling ‘list of musical frequencies’, note it mentions 440hz base and 12 tet, the starting point I suggested, there are dozens and dozens of other hits! https://homes.luddy.indiana.edu/donbyrd/Teach/MusicalPitchesTable.htm

I have tried this page before https://sevish.com/scaleworkshop to generate some of the more unusual scales.

@Tim the question doesn't imply that the app is supposed to be useful to any bass player.  Perhaps its target audience is guitarists who want to be able to practice with a bass line but don't know any bassists.  For a standard fretted instrument, the existence of flats is sufficiently acknowledged by recognizing their enharmonic equivalence with sharps.

@phoog - since OP states bass guitar specifically, that's a fair assumption. And I don't see how a guitarist can't practise bass lines on a standard guitar - my 1st band used an ordinary guitar as bass, albeit an octave too high (we were 14). Knowing Hz wouldn't have been any help at all. And my sharp/flat comment is proven  on several 'guitar' sites - not a flat in sight!

@Tim I was thinking of a computer substitute for music minus one -- not to practice the bass line but to be able to hear it while playing guitar chords.  I dabble in computer synthesis from time to time, mostly to model various questions of tuning, and often find myself singing along.

@OwenM: Thanks, I also found this one: https://nickfever.com/music/note-frequencies

The question is not asking for a way to go down a deep rabbit hole, but for those who do, the following book is very good: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/360876.Temperament

I committed this a while back. Resisting the temptation to read it now, to avoid getting trapped into rewriting it properly.

it's very simple, here it is in php. assuming you're using A4 = 440Hz and a bass guitar (12 tone equal temperament) which is in the question.
<?php
class Pitch extends IntegerValue
 {
    private const A4_FREQUENCY = 440.0;
    private const A4_DEGREE = 4*12+9;
    public function getFrequency(): float
     {
        $n = Pitch::A4_DEGREE - $this->getValue();
        $f = ((2.0**(1.0/12.0))**$n) * Pitch::A4_FREQUENCY;
        return $f;
     }
 }

or here in csv
C0,16.35
C#0,17.32
D0,18.35
D#0,19.45
E0,20.60
F0,21.83
F#0,23.12
G0,24.50
G#0,25.96
A0,27.50
A#0,29.14
B0,30.87
C1,32.70
C#1,34.65
D1,36.71
D#1,38.89
E1,41.20
F1,43.65
F#1,46.25
G1,49.00
G#1,51.91
A1,55.00
A#1,58.27
B1,61.74
C2,65.41
C#2,69.30
D2,73.42
D#2,77.78
E2,82.41
F2,87.31
F#2,92.50
G2,98.00
G#2,103.83
A2,110.00
A#2,116.54
B2,123.47
C3,130.81
C#3,138.59
D3,146.83
D#3,155.56
E3,164.81
F3,174.61
F#3,185.00
G3,196.00
G#3,207.65
A3,220.00
A#3,233.08
B3,246.94
C4,261.63
C#4,277.18
D4,293.66
D#4,311.13
E4,329.63
F4,349.23
F#4,369.99
G4,392.00
G#4,415.30
A4,440.00
A#4,466.16
B4,493.88
C5,523.25
C#5,554.37
D5,587.33
D#5,622.25
E5,659.26
F5,698.46
F#5,739.99
G5,783.99
G#5,830.61
A5,880.00
A#5,932.33
B5,987.77
C6,1046.50
C#6,1108.73
D6,1174.66
D#6,1244.51
E6,1318.51
F6,1396.91
F#6,1479.98
G6,1567.98
G#6,1661.22
A6,1760.00
A#6,1864.66
B6,1975.53
C7,2093.00
C#7,2217.46
D7,2349.32
D#7,2489.02
E7,2637.02
F7,2793.83
F#7,2959.96
G7,3135.96
G#7,3322.44
A7,3520.00
A#7,3729.31
B7,3951.07
C8,4186.01
C#8,4434.92
D8,4698.64
D#8,4978.03
E8,5274.04
F8,5587.65
F#8,5919.91
G8,6271.93
G#8,6644.88
A8,7040.00
A#8,7458.62
B8,7902.13


Wouldn't it be better to multiply the numerator of the exponent (i.e. 2**(n/12)) rather than exponentiate the semitone factor (i.e. 2**(1/12)**n) to reduce rounding errors?

no idea, the errors are eliminated if you use bc math anyway

Edit: no they're not because bcmath can't process fractions as exponent https://3v4l.org/t6qjA

@phoog In principle yes, but I think the error will be less than a billionth of a cent.

By several orders of magnitude, indeed, depending on what you mean by "billion."  I posted that comment before seeing the added table where the output is rounded to two decimal places.  But the errors would accumulate if one applied the function repeatedly.  Probably not to the point of being significant, though, even after a whole symphony's worth of sixteenth notes, of which there won't be more than several tens of thousands at most.

Goodness, three downvotes for the accepted answer.

@phoog it's not as elaborate but given the question I decided to answer it directly which the OP preferred. The answer by elements in space is definately the one to look at for a deeper understanding

Yes, I was criticizing the downvotes, not the answer.  Direct and to the point is often the best approach.  I tried to move that way in my answer, but you did so more, uh, directly.

In the 12-TET (12 Tone Equal Temperament) tuning system: we want the ratio of pitches in an octave to be 2:1, and we also want 12 (exponentially) equally spaced semitones per octave.  So, the frequency (fn) of a certain pitch n semitones above the frequency of an initial pitch (f0) is defined by the following formula:
  fn = f0 × 2n/12
(This means that the note 1 semitone above an initial pitch will have a frequency that is approximately 1.06 times greater, as 21/12 = 1.05946….)
Our initial pitch is usually chosen to set the frequency of A4 (the A above middle C) to be f0 = 440 Hz.
We can calculate the frequency of the notes by first finding how many semitones away we are from the initial pitch, and then plugging this value in for n into our formula.

For example, our highest note (F♯4) is 3 semitones below A4, so n = −3.  Putting this in, we have the frequency of F♯4:
  F♯4 = f−3 = 440 Hz × 2−3/12 = 370 Hz
For the lowest string on our bass guitar (E1), the note E is 5 semitones below A, but to get from A4 to E1 we need to go down a further 3 octaves, n = −5 − (3 × 12) = −41.  And so, the frequency of E1 is:
  E1 = f−41 = 440 Hz × 2−41/12 = 41.2 Hz

Musical tuning is a very complex subject.  As a starting point, you should surely take equal temperament as your basic approach.  Each fret raises the frequency by a factor of the twelfth root of two.
You can experiment with having the open strings tuned acoustically (the ratio of frequencies being 4:3) or in equal temperament (the ratio being 2(5/12)).
Specific bass guitars will further deviate from theoretical equal temperament because of design factors such as fret placement, bridge placement, and the like, as well as individual factors such as the weight and therefore tension of the chosen strings, and other adjustable parameters.  These variations are likely to be irrelevant to most applications of the sort you describe, and in any event many musicians will see them as problematic rather than desirable in many contexts.
All of the other things mentioned in comments and other answers amount to problems of emulating human performance.  Bass players can modify the pitch of their instrument by temporarily changing the tuning of a string or by using the fretting hand to push the string sideways, raising its tension, or with an effects pedal.
Depending on the application's requirements, this may or may not be significant.  If you find that your initial efforts are unsatisfactory, it may be that one reason for this is the difference between theoretical calculated frequencies and the actual frequencies produced by human musicians, but there are many more factors and details that are difficult to incorporate into computer synthesis that could be at play, for example volume, variable articulation, and tone color.

Downvote -- why?

This is correct but it's not useful to the poster who is looking for a table of frequencies or a method to calculate them (see the accepted answer and the top-voted one)

@PiedPiper this answer suggests a method to calculate them: "Each fret raises the frequency by a factor of the twelfth root of two.  You can experiment with having the open strings tuned acoustically (the ratio of frequencies being 4:3) or in equal temperament (the ratio being 2(5/12))."

I know nothing about guitar tuning and this answer may not apply to guitars, but it's worth noting that pianos are not tuned in frequency ratios of 21/12 even though they are nominally an equal-tempered instrument. The reason is that what makes two or more notes sound consonant (in tune) to the ear is alignment of the harmonics, not the ratio of the base frequencies. If the strings were ideal mathematical oscillators then the harmonics would be exact integer multiples of the base frequency and the two definitions would be equivalent, but the harmonics of real piano strings are slightly higher, so in the best key-agnostic compromise tuning (which is what equal temperament is), the ratio between consecutive base frequencies is slightly larger than 21/12. It varies with the pitch and also from piano to piano. There is software that aids in piano tuning, but you can't just tune each string to a base frequency determined by a mathematical formula and expect to get a good sound. You have to listen to the piano (or at least have the software do it).
See the Wikipedia article on stretched tuning for more.

This is true, and theoretically speaking at least it would apply also to bass strings to some degree or another as they are also thick and stiff, though I suspect somewhat less so than bass piano strings, which are under rather more tension.  For the purpose of computer synthesis of bass guitar pitches, though, theoretical 12-tone equal temperament is the only reasonable starting point.  I suppose that intonation issues related to bridge and fret placement are a likelier source of variation from calculated pitches than inharmonicity,

A hand-operated string instrument (bass guitar includded) is never tuned to an accuracy barely acceptable for a piano.

@fraxinus I'm not sure I understand your comment, but if you're saying that what I wrote doesn't apply to guitars, that doesn't surprise me much. I think it's worth pointing out the issue anyway since not everyone who reads the question will be specifically wondering about guitar tuning. I wish you hadn't downvoted it, if that was you.

@phoog Bass guitars, having thicker strings under less tension, are MORE inharmonic, and thus you'd expect to need MORE stretch when tuning.  In practice, though, most people don't stretch "enough" if at all, and so people are accustomed to the sound of less- or non-stretched bass tunings.

@benrg your answer is informative and only slightly off-topic, i am ok with that. My comment was exactly that the whole stretched tuning thing is irrelevant to guitars mainly because it is neither easy nor relevant to tune a guitar this much.

@Edward yes and no. It's true that an E-bass string is in principle more inharmonic than a piano string for the same frequency, however in practice the harmonics that end up coming out of the speaker aren't really the harmonics of the freely vibrating strings, but rather a complex interaction of the string vibration with fretboard buzzing, nonlinear pickup response, nonlinear amp response and nonlinear speaker response [the latter two not necessarily for bass (DI), but almost always for electric guitar]. All those nonlinear effects force the harmonics towards exact-integer-multiple.

@leftaroundabout The nonlinear effects add harmonics on top of the inharmonic overtones; the inharmonic tones are not shifted.  For my particular setup, the nonlinear effects are dominated by the natural overtones of the string, but it certainly could be the other way around for someone using a distortion/saturation effect.

@Edward: If the notes on a piano were only ever played one at a time, it would probably sound better if octaves weren't stretched.  Stretching the octaves, however, greatly improves the sound of notes which are played simultaneously.

There isn't a simple single formula as two different principles are being used. First is the frequency of the base (not the bass) note. For example, radio stations use A=440hz for the note A above middle C (different numbers are used by physicists and MIDI). Some orchestras tune to 442 or even 443 as their conductor may feel it sounds better.
Second is the ratio of notes to each other. These depend on the style of tuning. In equal temperament (called 12-tet in the tuning business for the case here) each half-step raised the frequency by the 12th root of 2, approximately 19/18 (as suggested by Vincenzo Galilei.) Other possibilities are tuning to "just" intervals like 5/4 for a major third, 3/2 for a perfect fifth, etc., or tuning all fifths to a ratio of 3/2. "You pays your money and you takes your choice."

I suspect tuning guitars with harmonics naturally leads to just intervals.

@Dekkadeci - that sounds like a god question.

"different numbers are used by physicists and MIDI", how come? Midi does not imply a frequency by itself as it just sends"note " information, and most synth are by default to produce a A at 440 Hz.

@Tom Pretty sure the "different numbers" refer to different systems for numbering each pitch, not frequencies. For example, scientific pitch notation calls middle C "C4". Yamaha electronic instruments and some software call middle C "C3". And MIDI labels middle C "60". I'm a little confused about the "radio stations" bit. When are radio stations tuning musical instruments?

Radio stations used to (and may still) broadcast a 440hz tone at times. I don't remember the details. There is a wiki and some other articles about the history of a frequency standard.

On a standard bass guitar, the difference between 12TET and pure 5ths is pretty small, as it uses only three consecutive 5ths from the circle of twelve (and 12TET fifths are pretty close to pure).

@gidds bass guitar strings are tuned in fourths. As with the fifth, the difference between the acoustically "pure" (a.k.a. "just") fourth and the equal-tempered fourth is tiny — less than 1/600th of an octave. This means that if you take A as your pitch reference, two strings will be off by that much and one will be off by twice as much.  If you use A=440 Hz, the G, the more out-of-tune, would be either 97.77 (repeating) Hz or 97.9989 Hz (rounded). The low E string would be either 41.25 Hz exactly or 41.2034 approximately. The beating caused by such small differences in frequency is very slow.

@ttw time synchronization stations broadcast various tones. The US stations use 440 Hz, 500 Hz, and 600 Hz. The Canadian station uses 1000 Hz tones, and the BBC pips are 1000 Hz (though apparently Arnold Dolmetsch wrote a piece for recorders and BBC pips and found that the pips were dropping in pitch as the oscillator wasn't linked to the time standard). The German station seems to have no audio tone per se. I don't believe the FCC requires US stations to broadcast any particular audio tones, but I have no idea about other countries.

@ToddWilcox fyi see my previous comment.  References: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WWV_(radio_station) / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHU_(radio_station) / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DCF77 / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Time_Signal / http://www.miketodd.net/other/gts.htm

Most of the information in this answer, while entirely correct, is not relevant to the question, which is asking about a standard bass guitar in standard tuning.
